# postgres and php: controlling changes done to a table

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'll try my best to explain my problem in english.
I created a database called Laboratory in which I want to control when a user inserts, deletes or updates a table. I called this table "tablaLog".

Basically tablaLog is updated by a trigger. It saves the information about who changed a determined table, the old data, the new data, the date, the user and the pid.
This is where I'm having the problem. The pid is the problem. Our teacher said that when, lets say an insertion is made (using a php form) we should look for its pid on the table "detalle_sesion" so we can now which user is making the change. Here it is the function I wrote for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION escuchar_cliente()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
res integer;
p int;

BEGIN
p = pg_backend_pid();
SELECT pid
INTO res
FROM detalle_sesion
WHERE pid = p;
IF res IS NOT NULL THEN
    DECLARE
        cod int;
        nombre character varying(20);

    BEGIN
        SELECT cod_usuario
        INTO cod
        FROM detalle_sesion
        WHERE pid = p;

        SELECT login
        INTO nombre
        FROM usuarios
        WHERE cod = cod_usuario;


        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO tablaLog (fecha, datoviejo, datonuevo, operacion, usuario, tabla, cod_tabla, cod_usuario)
            VALUES(now(), OLD.*, null, 'eliminar', nombre, 'Cliente', default, cod);
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO tablaLog (fecha, datoviejo, datonuevo, operacion, usuario, tabla, cod_tabla, cod_usuario)
            VALUES(now(), OLD.*, NEW.*, 'actualizar', nombre, 'Cliente', default, cod);
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO tablaLog (fecha, datoviejo, datonuevo, operacion, usuario, tabla, cod_tabla, cod_usuario)
            VALUES(now(), null, NEW.*, 'insertar', nombre, 'Cliente', default, cod);
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL;            
    END;
END IF; 
RETURN NULL;    
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

I can tell this function is not working since well...I doestn't inserst nothing on tablaLog. Some classmates are having the same problem and they say is due to the pid, that everytime a query is made a new pid is generated and it's not the same pid that is was saved on "detalle_sesion".

The table named "detalle_sesion" updates everytime a user logs on [cod_usuario, cod_sesion, ingreso, salida, pid] Here is how the table is updated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION detallesesion(logi character varying, pass character varying)
 RETURNS boolean AS
 $BODY$

DECLARE
res character varying (20);
pid int;    
cod int;

 BEGIN
SELECT cod_usuario 
INTO res 
FROM usuarios 
WHERE login = logi AND password = pass;
IF res IS NOT NULL THEN

    DECLARE 
        cod int;
        pid int;
        bs timestamp with time zone;
        qs timestamp with time zone;        

    BEGIN
        cod := CAST(res AS integer);
        pid = pg_backend_pid();

        SELECT backend_start, query_start
        INTO bs, qs
        FROM pg_stat_activity
        WHERE procpid = pid;

        INSERT INTO detalle_sesion(cod_usuario, cod_sesion, ingreso, salida, pid)
        VALUES (cod, default, bs, qs, pid);

        RETURN(TRUE);
    END;
ELSE
RETURN(FALSE);
END IF;
    END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

About php, I have the next:
conexion.php

```
<?php
$conexion = pg_connect("host=localhost
                        port=5432
                        user=postgres
                        password=postgres
                        dbname=labo") or
die ("no se pudo conectar".pg_last_error());
?>
```

manejadorDB.php All the functions with queries are here.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once "../funciones/conexion.php";
class manejadorDB
{
```

So I'm asking if there is a way to mantain the same pid since the user is logged on. Or maybe a different way to do the update of "tablaLog"

Comment: Make sure you're using an after trigger. Returning null on a before trigger cancels the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value returned by `pg_backend_pid()` will be different for any new connection made through `pg_connect()`, assuming there's no connection pooler in-between.

Also at some point this value will wrap around, as does the process ID under Unix (actually it is a process ID), meaning that new sessions will have the same `pid` of unrelated disconnected old sessions.

So this `pid` alone is not good as a durable session identifier from web clients. If there's a page to log on and other pages behind, the `pid` will be different for every page.

You may still use the `pid` in the trigger to look up the session, but you need to first establish a [session in php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) that is being kept between pages. The unique session ID should be inserted into `detalle_sesion` when the user logs in. Then, after every `pg_connect` call, the unique corresponding row in `detalle_sesion` should be updated with the new `pid` so that the trigger can find it.

Also since `pid` are reused, the `pid` alone is not sufficient. A combination of `pid` and `backend_start` would be better, since this combination is truly unique during any period of time.

Comment: I managed to insert the session ID on detalle_sesion, but as long as I was using the same browser with different session in each tab, the session id remained the same, so every time a new user logged I used session_regenerate_id().
The problem is, how after every pg_connect I identify that a determined row in detalle_sesion with that unique session ID needs to be updated I cant seem to stablish that relation between postgres and php.

Comment: I managed to made it work by updating the pid in the trigger of tablaLog everytime a query is made, and it works when one user is logged since the only condition I check to do the update of the pid is if the user is connected or not, so this aproach doesnt work when more ussers are connected

Comment: @VanessaVargas: you can't have different php sessions in browser tabs, (assuming the default: session ID is stored in a cookie), because all tabs share the same set of cookies. Use different browsers simultaneously, or different profiles with the same browser to simulate several users.

Comment: _how after every pg_connect I identify that a determined row in detalle_sesion with that unique session ID_: `update detalle_sesion set pid=pg_backend_pid() where php_session_id=?` and `?` is replaced by php's [`session_id()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)